# Тесты по ЭГЭ

Tags: тесты

Добрый вечер. Сегодня просматривая тесты ЭГЭ(см.ниже)( сразу отмечу, что ответ в тестах под номером 3. Заинтересовал такой вопрос: разве в слове "хр_нитель", безударная гласная редуцируется? В чем я очень сомневаюсь. А если не редуцируется, то и нет смысла ее проверять.Значит ответ неверный? Спасибо.

А14. В каком ряду во всех словах пропущена безударная проверяемая гласная корня?

1)    заг_релый, про_вляющийся, разув_рять
2)    эт_кетка, тр_вожиться, побл_дневший
3)    пож_леть, хр_нитель, д_йствительный
4)    разг_вор, в_ликолепный, отр_зиться

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Редуцируются все гласные, кроме ударных. В данном случае, на месте пропуска, по литературной норме, произносится "а-ослабленное" [ʌ], тот же звук мы слышим и в слове "п**[ʌ]**литик", но пишем "о".

Проверяемые безударные гласные в третьем варианте, проверочные слова: *жалко, охрана, действие*. В первом варианте чередование гласных в корне гор-гар ударением не проверить, с остальными случаями  вроде и так всё понятно.

Answer (score 0):

У Пушкина

Бопре в отечестве своем был парикмахером, потом в Пруссии солдатом, потом приехал в Россию pour être outchitel1), не очень понимая значение этого слова. Он был добрый малый, но ветрен и беспутен до крайности. Главною его слабостию была страсть к прекрасному полу; нередко за свои нежности получал он толчки, от которых охал по целым суткам. К тому же не был он (по его выражению) и врагом бутылки, т. е. (говоря по-русски) любил хлебнуть лишнее. Но как вино подавалось у нас только за обедом, и то по рюмочке, причем учителя обыкновенно и обносили, то мой Бопре очень скоро привык к русской настойке и даже стал предпочитать ее винам своего отечества, как не в пример более полезную для желудка. Мы тотчас поладили, и хотя по контракту обязан он был учить меня по-французски, по-немецки и всем наукам, но он предпочел наскоро выучиться от меня кое-как болтать по-русски, — и потом каждый из нас занимался уже своим делом. Мы жили душа в душу. Другого ментора я и не желал. Но вскоре судьба нас разлучила, и вот по какому случаю:

Прачка Палашка, толстая и рябая девка, и кривая коровница Акулька как-то согласились в одно время кинуться матушке в ноги, винясь в преступной слабости и с плачем жалуясь на мусье, обольстившего их неопытность. Матушка шутить этим не любила и пожаловалась батюшке. У него расправа была коротка. Он тотчас потребовал каналью француза. Доложили, что мусье давал мне свой урок. Батюшка пошел в мою комнату. В это время Бопре спал на кровати сном невинности. Я был занят делом. Надобно знать, что для меня выписана была из Москвы географическая карта.

Comment: К чему это, Вы, doom?

Comment: Извините, это предназначалось в качестве примера к другому вопросу: о двоеточии перед новым абзацем.

Comment: Понятно...